# App showing no error but crashing as soon as I press a button

Tags: android

I encountered this problem while trying to develop an android addition app and I tried to solve it by re-writing my code with making sure I don't make silly mistakes but I have no idea on how to solve it now.

I am trying to develop an android app which takes two numbers from the user and shows the sum of it, I think I am writing the correct code as their is no build errors or any problem highlighting and the app even opens but as soon as I write two numbers in the input numbers field and tap on the 'Calculate' button, my app crashes while I was expecting that the number would pop up in the TextView3.

The code of my XML file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Enter 1st no:"
        android:textSize="22sp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.159"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.119" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/editTextNumber2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:ems="10"
        android:inputType="number"
        android:textSize="20sp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/textView1"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.12" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Enter 2nd no:"
        android:textSize="22sp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.163"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/textView1"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.109" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/editTextNumber3"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:ems="10"
        android:inputType="number"
        android:textSize="20sp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.36"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/textView2"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/editTextNumber2"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.089" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button5"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Calculate"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.383" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView3"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textSize="34sp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.498"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/button5"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.087" />

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

The code of my Java file is:

```
package com.example.chapter1_futiletries;

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.EditText;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    private Button button5;
    private TextView textView1;
    private TextView textView2;
    private TextView textView3;
    private EditText editTextNumber2;
    private EditText editTextNumber3;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        button5 = findViewById(R.id.button5);
        textView1 = findViewById(R.id.textView1);
        textView2 = findViewById(R.id.textView2);
        textView3 = findViewById(R.id.textView3);
        editTextNumber2 = findViewById(R.id.editTextNumber2);
        editTextNumber3 = findViewById(R.id.editTextNumber3);
        button5.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                String editTextNumber2_value = editTextNumber2.getText().toString();
                int num1 = Integer.parseInt(editTextNumber2_value);
                String editTextNumber3_value = editTextNumber3.getText().toString();
                int num2 = Integer.parseInt(editTextNumber3_value);
                int finalNum = num1 + num2;
                textView3.setText(finalNum);
            }
        });
    }
}
```

I am using min SDK version 22 and targetSDK as 31 and I am trying to run it in the Pixel 4A and I am still learning android development so I could have made some mistakes and not understood them.

Comment: Use Logcat to examine the stack trace associated with your crash: https://commonsware.com/Jetpack/pages/chap-debug-001.html

Answer (score 0):

the error in line :

```
textView3.setText(finalNum);
```

because setText() should be filled always with string , As for the Integer , it is used to get String Resource , ex :

```
textView3.setText(R.string.appname);
```

> **The solution to your problem is :**

```
textView3.setText(String.valueOf(finalNum));
```

or :

```
textView3.setText(""+finalNum);
```